# spring - one context uses another one

Tags: spring, dependencies, applicationcontext

How to **import** one spring-context from another module's spring context?

```
module2 --uses--> module1
```

I have module1 and module2 (in my maven model), both are spring apps. Both projects are located on the same parent directory.

In module1 I have 'module1/Bean1' class (wich is a spring-bean)

The moodule2 is supposed to use module1. So, in the module2/src/main/resources/context2.xml I try to put 'reference' to context1 like this:

context2.xml:

```
 <import resource="classpath*:module1/resources/context1.xml" />
```

So, I'm expecting to use this code in the module2:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                        new String[] {"context2.xml"});
Bean1 bean1 = (Bean1) appContext.getBean("bean1"); // It uses bean defined in the module1
```

But now I have an exception:  **No bean named 'bean1' is defined**

-- context1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="module1"/>    <!-- for @Component, @Service, @Repository being scanned in particular folder -->
```

Comment: Have you declare module1 as a dependency of module 2 in pom.xml? If you did, <import /> tag should be workable.

Comment: it is in pom deps. (I have changed my code in the question - to show that Bean1 is available in the code)

Comment: Can we see your `context1.xml` file where `bean1` is defined? Are there any log messages which say that it failed to load the `context1.xml` file? Can you access other beans from the imported context file?

Comment: I've put it - see above. I defined it with annotation: @Component in the Bean1.java file

Comment: Yeah. I fixed it. Thanks. There was just stupid mistake in the context1.xml - in component-scan - was wrong package (my intellij idea did not resolve it, and I believed it was fine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you context1.xml is under /module1/src/main/resources/, instead of

```
<import resource="classpath*:module1/resources/context1.xml" />
```

You should use

```
<import resource="classpath*:context1.xml" />
```

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks. There was just stupid mistake in the context1.xml - in component-scan - was wrong package (my intellij idea did not resolve it, and I believed that everything was fine)